# What are these "Miser Run Desc" objectives in Temple Run 2?

Tags: temple-run-2

I have completed the Infinirunner objective in Temple Run 2, Level 9.

After I complete a run, no objective screen came up as usual, but if I go there from score screen, I see three objectives all named **Miser Run** with description "Miser Run Desc". These objectives don't show in OBJECTIVES if I go there from MENU, only the score screen.

Note that these aren't the Miser Run objectives which have the description "500m collecting no coins". I have long since completed that one.

Does anyone know what this is? This applies to both of these cases.

[image]

[image: A screenshot I thought would be helpful... So I took one :)]

Comment: I have run 500m collecting no coins, but it's not working

Comment: Which level are you in?

Comment: I have this same problem. Very annoying as I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: "Miser Run Desc" sounds like placeholder text. I'm betting this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically a bug or an unfinished piece of code. From [this thread](http://www.chaptercheats.com/qna/iphone-ipod/102696/Temple-Run-Answers.htm?qid=36563) you can see that many other people have it and one of the opinions is:

> This is a bug, an error, in the game. A "miser run" is one in which
>   you avoid collecting coins, but in this case no goal number has been
>   set. "Desc" is short for for description. The programer placed this
>   temporary text to remind himself (or someone else) to place
>   description text for the miser run. In the original Temple Run game a
>   Miser Run was running 500 meters without collecting any coins, so
>   either this was simply a repeat performance it it was actually code
>   that was copied over from the former game, but not completed. If you
>   look in the main current objectives list you'll see that it does not
>   show up. I was able to make this objective disappear by starting a run
>   and simply running off the first ledge without jumping.

So don't worry about it, it's just there to take some free space. It might be updated in the future with new objectives(I hope)

Answer (score 0):

Now it is finished, I've completed all 'miser-run-like' objectives, the longest of them was 1000 meters without single coin. I'm not sure if it's a bug or feature, but collecting any power-up has canceled the objective. Also note, that **first X meters from start** count. It's not enough to run 500 or 1000 meters without coins on any place in the game, it must be from start to the moment, where the message appears, that you have run for 500/1000 meters!

Comment: It's not that. This question does not relate to your situation. It appears much later when you are either in Level8/Level9. See the attached images.